# Hololens: Save edited PDF on onedrive

Tags: onedrive, hololens

I'm looking for a way to open, edit and save a fillable pdf file on OneDrive using the Hololens 2.
The only option I've found so far is to open the pdf from OneDrive using the browser, then edit it and save locally and later on upload the edited file into OneDrive. I'm looking for a simpler way to do it. Ideally: Open the file from OneDrive, edit it and save it automatically back into OneDrive.

Is there a different program I can use? The browser doesn't seem to let me save files to onedrive.

Or is there a way to auto sync a local folder's content to onedrive? I haven't been able to find this function so far.

Thanks a lot for any kind of help!